# Why does my Ruby method return an array instead of the string?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a question about Ruby return values which is baffling me.

I have written a method which takes an array as an argument and formats the array into a list as follows:

```
    def list(array)
        array.each { |name, age| puts name + " is #{age} years old" }
    end
```

Let's say the array is `[["Amy", 6], ["Tabitha", 5], ["Marcus", 9]]`.

I want this list method to return the strings in the do/end block, and not return the array. However, the return value is always an array.

I have tried assigning the block to a variable and returning the variable but it doesn't work. I also tried replacing `puts` with return but that then exits the method after the first iteration. Can't seem to work out what the problem is?

Sorry if this is a really silly question - I haven't come across it before.

Any input much appreciated, thanks! :)

Comment: `each` executes the given block for each element of the array, then returns the array itself. 
`puts` returns nil.
 You have to change `each` in to `map` and remove `puts` for this to work

Answer (score 6):

You want `map`, not `each`. `map` is like `each`, except it returns the result of each block evaluation. `each` returns the original array.
Also, and your main error here is that `puts` *display* something in the console, nothing else.

Your final code would be :

```
def list(array)
    array.map { |name, age| "#{name} is #{age} years old" }
end
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this but it then just returns an array of nil values. So when I used the method you suggested I got the following output in my terminal:

`Amy is 6 years old
Tabitha is 5 years old
Marcus is 9 years old
 => [nil, nil]`

Comment: jordan, when `how_old?` is defined this way `how_old?([["Amy", 6], ["Tabitha", 5], ["Marcus", 9]])` returns `["Amy is 6 years old", "Tabitha is 5 years old", "Marcus is 9 years old"]`.

Comment: You might have forgotten to remove `puts`. `puts` _displays_ its arguments, and returns `nil`. You want to return the string, not display it.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `each` is the list. The function returns that list since it is the last returnable instruction. You need to use the `map` method in the following way:

```
def how_old(people)
  people.map { |name, age| "#{name} is #{age} years old" }
end
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this but it then just returns an array of nil values. So when I used the method you suggested I got the following output in my terminal:

`Amy is 6 years old
Tabitha is 5 years old
Marcus is 9 years old
 => [nil, nil]`

Comment: How does this differ from @colinux's earlier answer?

Comment: Also, per [Ruby convention](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#bool-methods-qmark), the function should not be named with a `?`, as it doesn't answer a yes-no question.

Comment: There is no significant difference with @colinux's response, we did the same, your answer came before. @Amadan you are right, I will remove the symbol `?`. I renamed the functions just to give some semantics.